# Compute: Warn when low-order truncation occurs

Tags: cobol

I have a result field specified as

```
01 MY-RESULT VALUE +0 USAGE COMP-3 PIC S9(13)V99
```

Imagine I multiply two factors:

```
COMPUTE MY-RESULT = A * B
```

What is the best way to detect low-order truncation in `MY-RESULT`?
E.g. when `A=B=2.01`.

The `ON SIZE ERROR`clause is not triggered.

Comment: It's part of the Standard to do low-order truncation. ROUNDED can modify that slightly (to the 1985 Standard, five or higher in a single "extra" decimal position causes one unit of the lowest position defined in the result to be added to the result). Why do you need to know, I've never needed to know. I'd probably only do the multiplication if it were known not to cause low-order truncation (either multiplicand is zero in the decimal places, or both have zero in the low-order decimal position).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something that will work with all vendors and even the oldest compilers (as you did not specified any dialect the seems to be the most important part): if it matters use an additional target field with more decimal positions and check for equality afterwards:

```
COMPUTE MY-RESULT RESULT-WITH-MORE-DECIMALS = A * B
IF MY-RESULT NOT = RESULT-WITH-MORE DECIMALS
   ...
END-IF
```

`ON SIZE ERROR` will *only* be tracked for the upper truncation.

If this 2014 feature os available for your compiler you could use the `INTERMEDIATE ROUNDING IS PROHIBITED` (the draft had it in as `ROUNDED-MODE PROHIBITED`) which will show you this problem (if `EC-SIZE-TRUNCATION` exception is enabled). Beware of one part: this is an exception with a "fatal" category...

Comment: `COMPUTE MY-RESULT RESULT-WITH-MORE-DECIMALS = A * B IF MY-RESULT NOT EQUAL TO RESULT-WITH-MORE DECIMALS ... END-IF`

Comment: @BillWoodger - I've added the actual code and changed it from the explicit `MOVE` to "use two target fields" as proposed by you - saves one `MOVE` line

Comment: Nice idea with two target fields! Didn't know this is possible. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @KlausSchulz all arithmetic operations in COBOL operate on an intermediate field, the result is always copied (nearly identical to `MOVE`) and clauses like `ON SIZE ERROR` evaluated afterwards - therefore you can always use multiple targets.